# UnityEvents not drawing correctly on a Custom Editor

Tags: c#, unity-editor

I am trying to create a custom attribute called `DisplayIf` to use on several scripts in order to disable unused variables when certain conditions are met. The current problem is that the UnityEvent variable looses its fancy ui element of assigning and selecting a method when using the `DisplayIf` attribute as seen below.

[image: The OnInteract UnityEvent being drawn in a foldout style.]

The code for this attribute as well as the property drawer implementation is as follows:

Property Attribute;

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Utility.Attributes
{
    //Enum to add operator logic to create complex conditions
    public enum Operator
    {
        And,
        Or,
        Equals,
        Not
    }

    public class DisplayIfAttribute : PropertyAttribute
    {
       //Input list from the assigned variables on the attribute itself
        public List<object> conditions = new List<object>();


        public DisplayIfAttribute(params object[] args)
        {
            conditions.AddRange(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Property Drawer:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Extensions;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Utility.Attributes;

namespace Editor
{
    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(DisplayIfAttribute))]
    public class ConditionalDisplayPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
    {
        private DisplayIfAttribute _displayIfAttribute;
        private Dictionary<SerializedPropertyType, List<SerializedProperty>> _foundSerializedProperties;

        private List<object> _variables;

        public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property,
            GUIContent label)
        {
            _displayIfAttribute = attribute as DisplayIfAttribute;
            
            //Create dictionary to store the found property types in the argument.
            _foundSerializedProperties = new Dictionary<SerializedPropertyType, List<SerializedProperty>>();
            
            //Create object list that stores all the found values from both the properties and the static arguments present in the attribute.
            _variables = new List<object>();


            _displayIfAttribute?.conditions.ApplyAction(o =>
            {
                //Get the property and and its value.
                switch (o)
                {
                    case string p:
                        SerializedProperty foundProperty = property.serializedObject.FindProperty(p);
                        if (foundProperty != null)
                            switch (foundProperty.propertyType)
                            {
                                case SerializedPropertyType.Integer:
                                    _variables.Add(foundProperty.intValue);

                                    break;
                                case SerializedPropertyType.Boolean:
                                    _variables.Add(foundProperty.boolValue);

                                    break;
                                case SerializedPropertyType.Float:
                                    _variables.Add(foundProperty.floatValue);

                                    break;
                                case SerializedPropertyType.String:
                                    _variables.Add(foundProperty.stringValue);

                                    break;
                                case SerializedPropertyType.Color:
                                    _variables.Add(foundProperty.colorValue);

                                    break;
                                case SerializedPropertyType.ObjectReference:
                                    _variables.Add(foundProperty.objectReferenceValue.name);

                                    break;
                                case SerializedPropertyType.Enum:
                                    _variables.Add(foundProperty.enumValueIndex);

                                    break;
                            }

                        else
                            _variables.Add(p);

                        break;
                    //Check if the enum is an Operator and store said enum as an Operator. Otherwise, store its index
                    case Enum enumVal:
                        if (enumVal is Operator op)
                        {
                            _variables.Add(op);
                            break;
                        }

                        _variables.Add(Convert.ToInt32(enumVal));
                        break;

                    //Store the color if was given as an argument
                    case Color color:
                        _variables.Add(color);
                        break;
                }
            });

            bool canDisplay = false;

            //Create a list of lists that contain the results.
            List<List<bool>> result = new List<List<bool>>();
            
            //Create a list of operators.
            List<Operator> operators = new List<Operator>();
            int currentList = 0;


            //This for-loop increments by 3 as it will be looking at the next 3 elements, starting from i.
            //Look order: i > i+1 > i+2 (example 0, 1 ,2)
            //It also contains a check to see if the list is less or equal to 3, in which the loop will do a normal check on the element list size. Otherwise, it will check if the list count - 3 element offset is less or equal to the current index.
            for (int i = 0; _variables.Count >= 3 ? i <= _variables.Count - 3 : i < _variables.Count; i = i + 3)
            {
                result.Add(new List<bool>());
                object a;
                object b = null;
                object c = null;
                a = _variables[i];


                //The below if statements check if the next index is not outside of range.
                
                if (i + 1 <= _variables.Count - 1)
                    b = _variables[i + 1]; // 1

                if (i + 2 <= _variables.Count - 1)
                    c = _variables[i + 2]; // 2

                //This one checks whenever or not the 4th element is an operator, in which we store said operator when found.
                if (i + 4 <= _variables.Count - 1)
                {
                    object d = _variables[i + 4];
                    if (d is Operator newOp)
                    {
                        operators.Add(newOp);
                    }
                }


                //If only one argument exists, try to find a bool and get its value (since only bool variables can exist in just one argument)
                if (b == null || c == null)
                {
                    switch (a)
                    {
                        case bool value:
                            result[currentList].Add(value);
                            break;
                    }

                    //If the second element is not null, assume that the first element is an operator and try to find the Not Operator. Then, try to find if b is bool and store an inverted version of its value.
                    if (b != null)
                    {
                        if (a is Operator o)
                            switch (o)
                            {
                                case Operator.Not:
                                    if (b is bool moreValue)
                                    {
                                        result[currentList].Add(!moreValue);
                                    }


                                    break;
                            }

                        break;
                    }
                }

                //If the second value is an operator and all 3 values are not null, compare the first value with the third value and evaluate a true/false result based on the operator.
                if (b != null && b is Operator op && a != null && c != null)
                {
                    switch (op)
                    {
                        case Operator.Equals:


                            if (a is int val1 && c is int val2)
                            {
                                result[currentList].Add(val1 == val2);
                            }
                            else if (a is string text1 && c is string text2)
                            {
                                result[currentList].Add(text1.Equals(text2));
                            }
                            else if (a is Color color1 && c is Color color2)
                            {
                                result[currentList].Add(color1.Equals(color2));
                            }
                            else if (a is float float1 && c is float float2)
                            {
                                result[currentList].Add(float1.Equals(float2));
                            }

                            break;
                        case Operator.And:

                            if (a is bool bool1 && c is bool bool2)
                            {
                                result[currentList].Add(bool1 && bool2);
                            }

                            break;
                        case Operator.Or:
                            if (a is bool b1 && c is bool b2)
                            {
                                result[currentList].Add(b1 || b2);
                            }

                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }


                currentList++;
                
            }


            //If there is only one list of results, do a single check.
            if (result.Count == 1)
            {
                canDisplay = result[0].All(r => r);
            }
            else
            {
                int nextOperator = 0;
                
                //Similar to the previous for-loop, this loop checks itself and the next element per iteration.
                for (int j = 0; j <= result.Count - 2; j += 2)
                {
                    bool r1 = result[j].All(r => r);
                    bool r2 = result[j + 1].All(r => r);
                    Debug.Log($"If {r1} {operators[nextOperator].ToString()} {r2} are true");

                    switch (operators[nextOperator])
                    {
                        case Operator.And:
                            canDisplay = r1 && r2;
                            break;
                        case Operator.Or:
                            canDisplay = r1 || r2;
                            break;
                    }

                    //Increment the next operator and make sure that it does not get out of range from its list.
                    nextOperator++;
                    nextOperator = Mathf.Clamp(nextOperator, 0, operators.Count - 1);
                }
            }

            //Disable/Enable the field depending on the result of the above evaluations
            EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(!canDisplay);
            property.serializedObject.Update();
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label, true);
            property.serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
        }

        //Scale the field height depending whenever the property itself is expanded.
        public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            float height = base.GetPropertyHeight(property, label);
            if (property.isExpanded)
                height = SetHeight(property, height);


            height += 10f;
            return height;
        }

        private float SetHeight(SerializedProperty property, float height)
        {
            string lastPropPath = string.Empty;
            foreach (SerializedProperty p in property)
            {
                if (p.isExpanded && p.hasVisibleChildren)
                {
                    SerializedProperty foundProp = p.Copy();
                    height = SetHeight(foundProp, height);
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastPropPath) && p.propertyPath.Contains(lastPropPath)) continue;
                lastPropPath = p.propertyPath;
                height += base.GetPropertyHeight(p, new GUIContent(p.displayName));
            }


            return height;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is where the attribute is implemented so far:

```cs
 public enum EventType
        {
            OnInteract,
            OnProximityEnter,
            OnProximityExit,
            OnProximityStay
        }


        [SerializeField] private InteractionInput inputType;
        [SerializeField] private bool needsToBeLookedAtToInteract = true;

        [DisplayIf(Operator.Not,"useCustomEvent")] [SerializeField]
        private UnityEvent<PlayerController> onInteract;

        [DisplayIf(Operator.Not,"useCustomEvent")] [SerializeField]
        private UnityEvent onProximityEnter, onProximityExit, onProximityStay;

        [Space] [SerializeField] private bool useCustomEvent;

        [DisplayIf("useCustomEvent")] [SerializeField]
        private string customEventName;

        [DisplayIf("useCustomEvent")] [SerializeField]
        private EventType eventType;

        [DisplayIf("useCustomEvent")] [SerializeField]
        private Object[] args;
```

The logic written above is far from perfect or optimized. My current focus is to get this version of the attribute work with all variables and their custom editors which is currently not possible as seen with how the UnityEvent gets drawn.

I have done my share bit of research and the closest forum discussion i found towards this issue was [this one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unityevent-editor-in-custom-editor-window.338467/). I have yet to find an answer as of writing this post. Thus, here i am.

Comment: Do onProximityEnter and other events also not working?

Comment: Those events work fine. its just that the UI got reset to the ugly fold down style due to me trying to apply an attribute onto it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason it's displayed incorectly is becasue UnityEvents are drawn by a different class rather than PropertyDrawer.Under normal circumstances unity uses the class "UnityEventDrawer" to draw the Event. It derives from PropertyDrawer just like our own class. (This seems to be the reason its not working properly, because now we have two PropertyDrawers for the same thing). I just made my custom class inherit from it, and I called base.OnGUI() when I wanted the event to be displayed. **Don't forget to put** `using UnityEditorInternal`

I found the answer in this [thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/trouble-drawing-unity-event-in-property-drawer.887428/).
Here's an example from my code where I just introduced an attribute that adds foldouts to UnityEvents:

```cs
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditorInternal;//Boom
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(EventFoldoutAttribute))]
public class EventFoldoutPropertyDrawer : UnityEventDrawer//Boom
{

    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        if(!property.isExpanded)
            return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
        return base.GetPropertyHeight(property, label) + EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
    }
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        float lineHeight = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
        Rect foldoutRect = new (position.min.x, position.min.y, position.width, lineHeight);

        property.isExpanded = EditorGUI.Foldout(foldoutRect, property.isExpanded, new GUIContent(label.text+ " Event"));

        if (property.isExpanded)
            base.OnGUI(new(position.x,position.y + lineHeight, position.width, position.height - lineHeight), property, label);

    }





}
```